# Auto Generate control number base on input data

Tags: javascript

I am just a beginner in using javascript and I am having a hard time and figuring out how this problem. I want to Produce a control number base on the first character of the first name and last name. auto generate sequence number and last 2 digits of the present year.

sample control number: JS0001-18

JS = Jayson Smith (Name of the entry) // First Character of the Given and Surname

0001 = Sequence number.

18 = last 2 digits of the present year.

this code must have automatically appeared after I enter the first name of the student...

Thank you very much in advance, I hope you will help me with this problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getstudentNumber() {
    var lastnameFirstChar = $('#lastname').val().substr(0, 1);
    var firstnameFirstChar = $('#firstname').val().substr(0, 1);
    var studentID.value = lastname.value;
    var studentNumber = getSequence();
    document.getElementById("student_no").value = studentNumber;
    document.getElementById("student_no").focus();
    return true;
  }

  function getSequence(count, content) {
    var result = [];
    if (typeof content == "function") {
      for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        result.push(content(i));
      }
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        result.push(content);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  function getYearNumber() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getFullYear().val().charAt(0);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
  }
</script>
```

This is the HTML code

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Student Number</label>
  <input autofocus="" id="student_no" name="student_no" type="text" class="form-control" value="" onblur="getstudentNumber()"
  />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Last Name</label>
  <input id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control" value="" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>First Name</label>
  <input id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control" value="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You call the function `getNumber`, did you mean `getSequence`? I don't think the line starting `var studentID.value` works or is needed. Otherwise, looking great so far!

Comment: @Max i don't know what's next it was unfinished... all i need is to copy the initials of the student name sequence number and also the present year in last 2 digits automatically after i enter the first name. i was stock on this problem

Comment: @RaymondPeriabras Did you write this code, or has someone else given it to you and you're trying to fix it?

Comment: @Max on the function getstudentNumber i wrote it alone but in the last 2 function i just got it somewhere in the net and i am trying to rewrite it base on my needs

Comment: @Max on the function getYearNumber i just got it in w3 school the `var n = d.getFullYear()` i just added the `.val().charAt(0)` because is the last 2 digit of the year for example 2018 it must be -18

Comment: Why is PHP tagged here?

Comment: @Andreas sorry, it is just a mistake

Comment: Is "studentNumber" the sequence number; or where the output should go?

Comment: that is where the output should go from student name initials, sequence number and year of registration... it was incomplete because i dont know what to do next.

Comment: Note that there's no box to place the sequence number -- in my answer I have the JS keep track of it for you.

Comment: i never have a box because I want it to be auto generated in the student_no textbox.

Comment: @Max or I can create an input textbox and make it hidden in the form but it will generate a sequence number, what do you think?

Comment: @RaymondPeriabras I've created an answer -- I've renamed the `getStudentNumber` function to `gatherDataAndOutput` -- I'm confident you can adapt it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

## Extract Initials

**NOTE** This answer assumes that the element "student_no" is for *output*, and the JS should keep track of the student number with a global variable.

As you said, the student number is composed of three blocks. The name, the number, and the year. We could create a function for each one.

```
function getInitials(firstName, lastName) {
  return (firstName[0] + lastName[0]).toUpperCase()
}
```

Note that `[0]` is the same as `.substr(0, 1)`. The use of square brackets will only ever allow for a single character -- but that's all we need in this case.

We add `.toUpperCase()` to make sure that even if you enter lowercase names, you still get uppercase initials.

## Get Short Year

Next, it looks like your `getYearNumber` function is a little bit broken. Let's write one from scratch. It needs to:

- Generate a new date object
- Extract the year

Now, we *could* extract the year as a two-digit code straight away. However, this has been deprecated, so we'll need to do it ourselves.

```
function getYear() {
  var now = new Date()
  var fullYear = now.getFullYear()
  var shortYear = fullYear % 100
}
```

The `% 100` finds the remainder when you divide by 100. `2018`, the year of writing, when divided by 100, yields 20 remainder **18**. Perfect! We can make the function shorter by not storing our intermediate values in variables.

```
function getYear() {
  return (new Date).getFullYear() % 100
}
```

**NOTE** There is the scary "Year 2000" problem. This won't matter for another millennia though ;)

The reason why your theory of `.val().charAt(0)` wasn't quite correct is that numbers don't have `.val()`, and if you wanted to convert it to a string, `.charAt(0)` would only give you the first character (this would be a `2` in `2018`). Hope that helps?

## Zero-padded Number Strings

We could now create a function that takes a `Number` (like 72); and creates a string with padded zeros (like `0072`)

```
function paddedNumber(number) {
  var numberAsString = number.toString()
  var numberLength = numberAsString.length
  var numberLengthRemaining = 4 - numberLength
  var zeros = "0".repeat(numberLengthRemaining)
  return zeros + numberAsString
}
```

We can make that a lot shorter.

```
function paddedNumber(number) {
  return "0".repeat(4 - number.toString().length) + number
}
```

`String + Number` will always be `String`.

There's one problem. Some browsers don't support the modern `.repeat()`. So, instead, let's replace it with a for-loop.

```
function paddedNumber(number) {
  var result = ""
  for(var i = 4 - number.toString().length; i > 0; i--) {
    result += "0"
  }
  return result + number
}
```

Wonderful!

## Wrapper Function

Now let's put this all together with a big function that clobbers it all together.

```
function makeStudentID(firstName, lastName, studentNumber) {
  return getInitials(firstName, lastName) + paddedNumber(studentNumber) + getYear()
}
```

## Data Collection and Output

Finally, we need to gather up the data!

```
var sequenceNumber = 1
function gatherDataAndOutput() {
  var firstName = document.getElementById("firstname").value
  var lastName = document.getElementById("lastname").value
  var outputElement = document.getElementById("student_no")

  outputElement.value = makeStudentID(firstName, lastName, sequenceNumber)

  sequenceNumber++; // make a different ID for the next student.
}
```

## All together

The JS code would look something like this (hopefully this will point you in the correct direction).

```
function getInitials(firstName, lastName) {
  return (firstName[0] + lastName[0]).toUpperCase()
}

function getYear() {
  return (new Date).getFullYear() % 100
}

function paddedNumber(number) {
  var result = ""
  for(var i = 4 - number.toString().length; i > 0; i--) {
    result += "0"
  }
  return result + number
}

function makeStudentID(firstName, lastName, studentNumber) {
  return getInitials(firstName, lastName) + paddedNumber(studentNumber) + getYear()
}

var sequenceNumber = 1
function gatherDataAndOutput() {
  var firstName = document.getElementById("firstname").value
  var lastName = document.getElementById("lastname").value
  var outputElement = document.getElementById("student_no")

  outputElement.value = makeStudentID(firstName, lastName, sequenceNumber)

  sequenceNumber++; // make a different ID for the next student.
}
```

## HTML

I reordered your HTML, added the renamed function, and disabled our output input so that you cannot type in it, only view and copy from it. These are only stylistic changes (apart from renaming the function). Note that the output **only** changes when the second input is blurred -- not the first. It might help to add a button, because at the moment, the ID is changed whenever you blur the second input, even if it's accidental.

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control" onblur="gatherDataAndOutput()"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Student Number</label>
    <input autofocus="" id="student_no" name="student_no" type="text" class="form-control" disabled onblur="gatherDataAndOutput()"
    />
  </div>
```

## Live

Live version: https://MustySandyFolder--joker314.repl.co

Comment: Thank you very much for giving time to my question, I shall study it this will be a very useful even to my future endeavors.

Comment: can I use onBlur or OnKeypress so that it can be auto generate while i type ll the informtion?

Comment: @RaymondPeriabras Absolutely! In your HTML code, just swap out `getstudentNumber` with `gatherDataAndOutput` (or, do the reverse in the JS). Note that since the first element is storing the output, you might want to put it at the bottom and don't put the `onblur` there! Instead, add it to the "firstname" and "lastname" input areas in your HTML. You might want to add some extra checks (such as placing a `?` if the input is empty) so that there are no errors if only one box has been completed. I'll see if I can make you a working bit of code.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH YOU SAVE MY DAY FROM MY PROFESSOR.

Comment: Just one more thing, I spotted a mistake in my for loop in the `paddedNumber` function that will make the code crash the browser. I'll edit now! Whoops :D

Comment: yes i notice it and it says in chrome, aw snap.... its ok we are not perfect everyone can commit mistakes sometimes

Comment: @RaymondPeriabras Okay, I've fixed the mistake; and added a live version ( https://repl.it/@joker314/MustySandyFolder ). I include an onblur in the second input (the "First Name"). Trouble is, whenever you blur that input... it changes the ID. Should there be a manual "Change ID" button? Also, I don't think blindly copying and pasting code will help you nor the professor, if you don't understand anything -- please do ask. In addition, to show an answer helped you, you can mark it as the accepted solution, or give it an upvote :D

Comment: Thank max for the code one more problem, when i enter a new student after i login again the sequence number reset to 00001 the problem is that when i enter a student with the same initial i am generating the same set of student number. but code is very useful... the only problem is that after i login again in the web app

Comment: You could store the data locally with `localStorage`; or, you could use a random number generator (`Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000 + 1)`).

Comment: if i use math random it only generate random number but not sequential, am I correct?

Comment: That's right, yeah. You might want to store the data in localStorage (for example, you could replace the line `sequenceNumber++` with `localStorage.sequenceNumber++` -- and, at the start, you could replace `var sequenceNumber = 1` with `localStorage.sequenceNumber = localStorage.sequenceNumber || 1`

Comment: I really *really* encourage you to talk with your professor about the concepts I've used. It's important you understand the code you're writing.