# Autogenerate Case ID With Conditional Letter Prefix, Next Avail Number, and Current Year

Tags: c#, razor, razor-pages, auto-generate

I have researched this and have in mind how to do parts of it, but don't quite understand how to put it all together. When someone is creating a new record in my app, if the results of the `InvestigationLog.CourtType` dropdown is either "Transfer In (F)" or "Transfer In (M)", then I need to fill a text field, `InvestigationLog.TCaseNo` with a Case Number, but ONLY if it is one of those two choices. (There are other choices besides these two that should be disregarded.)

The case number needs to be in the format of `T(then F or M depending upon the 2 choices above)-###-YY`. For example, `TF-001-24` would be the first F case of 2024.

My current .cshtml for this field is:

```html
<td style="width: 25%">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label asp-for="InvestigationLog.TCaseNo"></label>
        <input asp-for="InvestigationLog.TCaseNo" id="TCaseNumber" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
    </div>
</td>
```

And the .cshtml for the Investigation.CourtType field is:

```
                <td style="width: 25%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="InvestigationLog.CourtType"></label>
                        <select asp-for="InvestigationLog.CourtType" id="SelectCourtType" class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplayCourtTypeData.OrderBy(x => x.CourtTypeDesc),"CourtTypeDesc", "CourtTypeDesc"))" onchange="assignCaseNo" ><option value="" selected disabled>---Select Court Type---</option></select>
                    </div>
                </td>
```

I would like this `TCaseNo` to populate once someone has tabbed out of the `InvestigationLog.CourtType` dropdown. If they go back (before submitting and binding the record) to change the value of the `CourtType` dropdown, I would like it to change accordingly.

In my research on here, I have come up with the code below to increment the 'F' and 'M' `TCaseNo`:

Just don't know enough Javascript to do this correctly. I "think" I am pretty close. Just can't get my values to populate the .TCaseNo field on my create view.

Also, should I be doing one set of the variables that are the same for each outside of the if?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function assignData() {
            const assignCT = $("#SelectCourtType").val().trigger('input');
        }

    function updateTCaseNumber('#TCaseNumber') {
        if ('#SelectCourtType').val() = "Transfer In (F)"
        {
            var year = DateTime.Now.Year;
            int incFCaseNo = 0;
            "F" + String.Format("{0:000}", incFCaseNo, year);
            incFCaseNo++;
        }
        else if('#SelectCourtType').val() = "Transfer In (M)"
        {
            var year = DateTime.Now.Year;
            int incMCaseNo = 0;
            "M" + String.Format("{0:000}", incMCaseNo, year);
            incMCaseNo++;
        }
        else
        {
            null
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#SelectCourtType').on('input', updateTCaseNumber);
        });

    }
</script>
```

THIS PART ANSWERED BELOW. I DO NOT NEED TO FREE UP NUMBER AND REUSE IT: I'm also not sure how to deal with the auto-generated number after the fact? For example, someone later wants to edit the `CourtType` and it is no longer a Transfer type. Should that `TCaseNo` be freed up to reuse? What happens to it? Is there standard practice on this?

If you can assist, please do.

EDITED TO ADD: Recently found this thread after many trial searches for the right words: [Auto Generate control number base on input data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51454906/auto-generate-control-number-base-on-input-data)

Looks like what I am looking for, except I still need help sussing out the CourtType dropdown to filter out the 'Transfer In (F)" and the "Transfer In (M)" values and use them to prefix the numbers. (NOTE: Each F and M case series needs to have their own 001+ series of numbers, ie NOT TF-001-24, TM-002-24, TM-003-24, TF-004-24, etc) Please HELP!! Nothing working yet.

Latest Javascript edit:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        
        let incFCaseNo = 1;
        let incMCaseNo = 1;
        
        function updateTCaseNumber(e) 
        {
        
            const input = $('#TCaseNumber');
            
            // value will be "Tranfer in (F)" or "Transfer in (M)"
            
            const selected = $('#SelectCourtType').val();

            if (selected === "Transfer In (F)") {
                // only take 2 digits of the year
                const yearF = new Date().getFullYear() % 100;
                // const caseNoF = "TF" + selected + String(incFCaseNo).padStart(3, '0') + year;
                const caseNoF = `TF-${String(incFCaseNo).padStart(3, '0')}-${yearF}`;
                input.val(caseNoF);
                incFCaseNo++;
            }
            else if (selected === "Transfer In (M)") {
                // only take 2 digits of the year
                const yearM = new Date().getFullYear() % 100;
                // const caseNoM = "TM" + selected + String(incMCaseNo).padStart(3, '0') + year;
                const caseNoM = `TM-${String(incMCaseNo).padStart(3, '0')}-${yearM}`;
                input.val(caseNoM);
                incMCaseNo++;
            }
            else { 
                input.val("");
            }
            
        }
    
    </script>
```

The javascript above will give me either a TF or TM number, but if I toggle between Transfer In (M) and Transfer In (F) in the dropdown, it will keep incrementing the sequence number. For example, if I pick Transfer In F, I will get TF-001-24. If I then toggle to Transfer In M, I will get TM-001-24. All good. BUT, if I toggle back to Transfer In F, I will then get TF-002-24. Not good. I can see in the code where the placement is making it do this, but do not know WHERE to place the increment so that it will increment AFTER I hit the submit button on the create page.

Can someone explain how I would do that?

Comment: I'l go on a limb and say: create one SQL table for each year and "F" and "M" and use an "IDENTITY" column for the "auto key". The F, M, and year are implied in the Table Name: F24 or M24. You can "UNION" (merge) them later if need be (with identifiers). 20 tables over 10 years. Manageable.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am hoping to have a number that someone does not have to manage. You seem to be suggesting that someone would create 2 tables every year just to give out a case number? Why can't it just be calculated?

Comment: An "IDENTITY" column automatically generates a new number when you add a record (i.e case). No "management" required; that's the point: it's an auto-incrementing number.  If you have no experience with SQL database, then my comment is not appropriate ... and I withdraw it. Sorry.

Comment: I understand SQL database, but it appears you are suggesting that I create a table for each year, for each type - and I won't be at this location to do this for them for much longer. Can you elaborate how this would work in this specific example?

Comment: You haven't described a "use case"; I assume you want some sort of ledger. A table would serve as a ledger. I avoided a single table for simplicity: all you need is the IDENTITY column. I develop "user interfaces". For me to create a "UI" where you say "Give the the next number for F and 24" .... I can do that in "one hour"; including an SQL server "database" and an ORM (EF) that does any "table switching". It's just the type of app one tends to build for someone who has been using Excel to do the same thing.

Comment: My apologies. I thought I did. It will be used as an additional reference number in a case log. Some cases will have it (if their CourtType is as described above), others will not. These cases already have a unique id.

Comment: The id that you describe shouldn't be generated client side, but rather server-side to eliminate the possibility that two users could generate the same id. It seems that you may not possess the necessary skills to complete this task. The judicial system has a significant impact on peoples' lives and isn't something where one should be learning basic programming skills. You may consider asking your manager to assign the task to someone else.

Comment: This is a tiny internal app used for tracking. It will not impact negatively on anything. Put your mind at ease. This number does not go to any court. If there were an error in it, it would not impact anyone's life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved by simple JS, I recommend you learn JS if you are serious with your career. But here is how it can be done, I'm assuming you are using JQuery, please notice the  tag in the head of the document if you haven't done it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    

    <!-- Include JQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <td style="width: 25%">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label ></label>
            <input  id="TCaseNumber" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
        </div>
    </td>    
    <td style="width: 25%">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label ></label>
            <select  id="SelectCourtType" class="form-select" onchange="updateTCaseNumber(event)" >
                <option value="" selected disabled>---Select Court Type---</option>
                <option value="F">Transfer In (F)</option>
                <option value="M">Transfer In (M)</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </td>

<script type="text/javascript">
    let incFCaseNo = 0;
    function updateTCaseNumber(e) {
        const input = $('#TCaseNumber');
        
        // value will be "F" or "M"
        const selected = $('#SelectCourtType').val();

        if (selected === "") {
            input.val("");
        } else {
            // only take 2 digits of the year
            const year = new Date().getFullYear() % 100;
            // const caseNo = "T" + selected + String(incFCaseNo).padStart(3, '0') + year;
            const caseNo = `T${selected}-${String(incFCaseNo).padStart(3, '0')}-${year}`
            input.val(caseNo);
            incFCaseNo++;
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply and sample. I would definitely take the time to learn JS for my career, but I am at the end of my career with less than 3.5 months to go. So, it would be fruitless. I still try to do what I can on my own to provide value until that time.

Comment: As far as the sample code goes, I actually need separate TM and TF sequences. Ie, I need to be able to have a TM-001-24 and a TF-001-24. I tried moving things about in your code and making your 'else' into an 'else if' and then adding an 'else' for the MCaseNo. along with adding the needed variable, but I am getting an error. The case number field does  not populate and my validation tells me I need the CourtType filled in (which I did, but not it appears not to bind/take. Suggestions? I will update my code in my original post for you to see.

Comment: Also, I do have jquery. It is in a shared layout file.

Comment: Dropdown also has other choices that need to be ignored. I wouldn't know how to assign the value field as you are doing. It is not a static list of options. New ones can be added by the user. I just want the TCaseNumber field blank if it isn't a Transfer in (F) or a Transfer in (M) court type.

Comment: @MelB Look it up, your problem with the selected value is not that hard to find an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc

Comment: Worked on code more and got some working. Added update with more questions. Can you please assist? I need to get this done and am spinning my wheels. It is hard to research when I don't know what exactly I am looking for and what I am reading (what it means) when I find something.

Comment: I'll give you some ideas to help you continue your research. 1. If you only want to increment the number when the form is submitted, you should store the auto-increased number in your database and handle the increment on the server-side. Then, when the page loads, fetch the latest number and concatenate it to form the correct caseNo instead of incrementing your incFCaseNo variable in JavaScript as you're doing right now. The error re CourType means you're not sending the CourtType data to the server for validation. Open Chrome DevTools and examine the request to see what data is being sent.

Comment: I was able to suss out my issue on the submit and it submits fine now. However, as I guessed from my on-page testing, when I create a new form the increment starts all over at 1 again. The number is being stored in my database model along with the other fields on the form. So, are you saying to store the 3 digit number on its own, so I would have 2 number fields instead of one (ie, 1,2,3 AND TF-001-24, TF-002-24, TF-003-24) And would the 1,2,3 number be in a separate table (something like Gerry Schmitz was suggesting in above comments?

Comment: I need something that doesn't require intervention each year to start the sequence over again.

Comment: The problem you've mentioned is more complex than just something you do right now. You probably need a table with an unique constraint on 3 columns "Year", "CourtType", "Number". I don't know if you want the `caseNo` to be unique system-wide or just for individual users, you have to figure that out and update the unique constraint accordingly. But the unique constraint gonna help you with all sorts of concurrency issues, then you only need to work on the logic to form `caseNo` in the backend i.e: retry when you fail to insert a key that already exists (by increasing the "number")

Comment: On the client, you can use the latest value of `caseNo` and then increase its number by 1 to show to the users, but the users can't expect the number they see to be the actual number gonna be stored in the database, because maybe the concurrency occurs and someone else has already taken the number, so after they submit the form, you perform the aforementioned insert logic, and show them the real value that you've inserted (if it's important for the users to know)

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of rule that should be decided by the "business". It's the same kind of question as, "Must the identity be an un-broken sequence?" for numeric IDs.

Generally speaking if you have an ID that can be computed based on aspects of the object (a type/flag) and the conditions under which it was created (date, location, etc) then those things need to *always* accurately represent the object. Otherwise the standard is useless.

That means that if one of those attributes can be changed after the fact, the standard must allow for it. Imagine if you made `TF-001-24`, and someone changes it so that it needs to be `TM-001-24`, but later decides no wait... it really is a `TF` one. If you allow that original ID to be used by something else after the switch, you have broken the standard because now you either cannot change the initial case back to an `F`, or you **can** but the ID can't change. In the second situation you've officially negated the purpose of the computable ID.

In the standard you've provided, the `001` is not a *subset* of `TF` or `TM`. It is a standalone counter. You don't need to know if it's the first of its kind for the year, because that's technically not knowable if you can change the type after it was created.

My favorite issue tracker uses a modified version of this scheme where the shortcode for a Project is the prefix, and the number is the sequence of the issue within that Project. So `BC-123`, `IR-456`, etc. But the Project field can be changed! If I move `BC-123` from Project `BC` to `IR` it becomes `IR-457`. But what about the old ID? Well, it's still mapped to that issue actually. So any links to `BC-123` that might exist out in the world still work, and will take you to `IR-457`. If I change the Project back to `BC` it goes back to the original ID of `BC-123` and now any links for `IR-457` will lead there instead.

When it comes to computed IDs there must always be something about it that is unique, but not the whole thing. In your case the number of the case per the given year is that unique thing. There will always be an order to the cases being made, and so long as you don't need to worry about gaps in your IDs overall there's no reason that every other aspect of the case that you might put into the ID can be changed whenever.

The more important part here is that `001-24` will be enough to get you to that case no matter what other values exist. Think of it like the issues in that tracker. If part of the ID can change, the old ones must remain valid or else any references that exist frozen in time like on a sticky note or an email will be invalid.

Comment: Thanks very much for your thoughts on that. Makes sense and is much appreciated. This is a very simple app (well, except for that javascript!), so I don't think the number matters so much what it is (sequence-wise) just so long as the type (TF or TM) is correct and the year is correct. The old app (which I cannot access the coding for, appears to be that you cannot change the number AT ALL once it is assigned!